# SIMULINK: upperBoundSize.isUnknown()

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to simulate a feedback loop in simulink involving PID controllers and optimization algorithm. 
I have individual bits of code that run well, but when i put them together I'm getting errors. The errors do not pin-point at anything, but I have traced it to use of MUX in the code.
I'm attaching the pic of the MUX causing the error, the output of max should be 3 but its 1 instead and the rest of matlab function gives error like

```
upperBoundSize.isUnknown()

Simulink does not have enough information to determine output sizes for this block. If you think the errors below are inaccurate, try specifying types for the block inputs and/or sizes for the block outputs.

Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 3. The valid range is 1-1.

Undefined function or variable 'TyR'. The first assignment to a local variable determines its class.
```

This code works well in other place.
[image]

Comment: You'll probably find it's not the MUX block.  The `1` you are seeing is most likely determined by an upstream block that you haven't shown in your image.  Note the error you show says `Undefined function or variable ``TyR```, what is that?